# Car available or unavalible between date and time slot in car rental Project Laravel

Tags: laravel-5.8

I am trying to build a Car rental reservation process with Laravel 5.8.

I want to show all the cars as available while the car is not found at the `Reservation` table between specific
`pick_up_date` and `drop_off_date` with time.

**What i have now?**

I have `pick_up_date`, `pick_up_time` also `drop_off_date`, `drop_off_time` too and `vehicle_id`.

I am able to figure out which cars are available and unavailable while my `pick_up_date` and `drop_off_date` are same.

But my problem with `drop_off_date`.

Let me explain it in details :

Guess i am trying to book a reservation and my

pick_up_time = "23:45:00" AND pick_up_date='2020-09-05' 
pick_up_time = "04:28:00" AND pick_up_date='2020-09-06'

[image: When pickup and drop off date same this query working perfectly.]

Note : `pick_up_date`, `drop_off_date` DATABASE DATA TYPE IS : `date` and `pick_up_time`, `drop_off_time` Database data type is `time`.

How to make query, when `pick_up_date` and `drop_off_date` are not the same also with time slot checking?

Comment: Are you using `Carbon`?

Comment: yes i am. @smartrahat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$found= Reservation::query()
        ->where('vehicle_id', $id)
        ->where(function($exits) use ($start_timestamp,$end_timestamp)
        {
            $exits->where(function ($findConflict) use ($start_timestamp,$end_timestamp) {
                $findConflict->whereBetween('start_timestamp',[$start_timestamp,$end_timestamp])
                    ->orWhereBetween('end_timestamp',[$start_timestamp,$end_timestamp]);
            })
            ->orWhere(function($middleClause) use ($start_timestamp,$end_timestamp) {
                $middleClause
                    ->where('start_timestamp','<=',$end_timestamp)
                    ->where('end_timestamp','>=',$start_timestamp);
            });
        })
       ->get();
    if ($found->count()>0){
        echo $available = 0;
    }else{
        echo  $available = 1;
    }
```

Raw sql : `select * from` reservations`where`vehicle_id `= yourVehicleId and ( (`start_timestamp`between YourStartingDateTime and yourEndingDateTime or`end_timestamp `between YourStartingDateTime  and yourEndingDateTime  ) or (`start_timestamp`<= yourEndingDateTime and`end_timestamp `>= YourStartingDateTime) )`